# Can I visualize a MTLTexture in debug?

Tags: swift, xcode, metal

How can I visualize a MTLTexture during the debug in Xcode. I tried to use the quick look but it's not showing the texture, just a pop a card with the content:
[quick look result for a object of type MTLTexture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IKarc.png)

Comment: [Viewing Your Frame Graph](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/debugging_tools/viewing_your_frame_graph?language=objc)

Answer (score 0):

You can add a breakpoint before calling [`buffer`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/)[`.commit()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metal/mtlcommandbuffer/1443003-commit) that you expect the MTLTexture should have some value. If you have two or more command queues, you can label your queue before capturing.

```swift
queue.label = "Make Integral"
```

When the breakpoint is active, then you can now capture and set the scope associate with the label.

[image]